# Onclick is not defined - EventListener null

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

The problem is that the onlclick returns "main.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: removePost is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (main.html:1)" I need to load the function removePost to erase the post with the specific id. After that I tried the same trick but with the eventListener (see in the final of the code) but returns null, the html reference it seems to be out of scope. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at main.js:70.

Any ideas? thx in advance.

**HTML**

```
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Count Likes</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="root"></div>
    <div class="CountLike" id="Like Count">
      <button class="button button1">
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like <span class="counterStat">...</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="formContainer">
      <input id="nameInput" type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" />
      <input id="bodyInput" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa comentario" />
      <button id="btnSend">Publicar</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody id="table"></tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBoHBd8UGJ2oFxyEu9lqbIWmg_j-MvcYZQ",
        authDomain: "like-button-2203f.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://like-button-2203f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "like-button-2203f",
        storageBucket: "like-button-2203f.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "949206080621",
        appId: "1:949206080621:web:8b2146c19e8c082b913364",
        measurementId: "G-REJZ56MGNY",
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      //   firebase.analytics();
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const dCounters = document.querySelectorAll(".CountLike");

[].forEach.call(dCounters, function (dCounter) {
  const el = dCounter.querySelector("button");
  const cId = dCounter.id;
  const dDatabase = firebase.database().ref("Like Number Counter").child(cId);

  // get firebase data
  dDatabase.on("value", function (snap) {
    const data = snap.val() || 0;
    dCounter.querySelector("span").innerHTML = data;
  });

  // set firebase data
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    dDatabase.transaction(function (dCount) {
      return (dCount || 0) + 1;
    });
  });
});

document.getElementById("btnSend").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
  let body = document.getElementById("bodyInput").value;
  db.collection("post")
    .add({
      name: name,
      body: body,
    })
    .then(function (docRef) {
      console.log("id ", docRef.id);
      document.getElementById("nameInput").value = "";
      document.getElementById("bodyInput").value = "";
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error ", error);
    });
});

const table = document.getElementById("table");
db.collection("post").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  table.innerHTML = "";
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // console.log(`${doc.id}=>${doc.data().name}`);
    table.innerHTML += `
      <tr>
        <th scope='row'>${doc.id}</th>
        <td>${doc.data().name}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().body}</td>
        <td><button onclick="removePost('${doc.id}')" 
        id="btnRemove" class="far fa-trash-alt"></button></td>
        <td><button id="editPost" class="far fa-edit"></button></td>
      </tr>`;
  });
});

function removePost(id) {
  db.collection("post")
    .doc(id)
    .delete()
    .then(function () {
      console.log("Removed");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error - " + error);
    });
}
```

**EventListener**

```
document.getElementById("btnRemove").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  db.collection("post")
    .doc(evt.target.doc.id)
    .delete()
    .then(function () {
      console.log("Removed");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error - " + error);
    });
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("btnRemove")` will not work anyway if you would because you cannot have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: If `removePost` is not being found, sounds like it is in a different scope. Is that exactly what is in that JavaScript file?

Comment: 1st Q. There's is only one element named btnRemove.
2nd Q. My entire JS is on the post.
Thx again

Comment: "There's is only one element named btnRemove" No there is not unless you are using a for loop to only generate one button.

Comment: The problem is `type="module"` does not have global variables.